# Flutter IOS release size more than 400Mb

Tags: ios, flutter, size, release

New to Flutter. I'm working on this app and on "flutter build ios --release" command is 407Mb on size, with apk instead i have 25Mb. I've tried downgrade flutter without results, still the same sizes even if my assets folder is just 8.6Mb. This is my yaml file:

```
name: ragogna
description: Nuova app per la comunita.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  share: ^0.6.3+5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  sliver_fill_remaining_box_adapter: ^0.1.1
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  provider: ^3.2.0
  add_2_calendar: ^1.3.1
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/event_images/
    - assets/locations/
    - assets/itinerari/

  fonts:
    - family: Kievit
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Kievit-Book.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Kievit-Medium.ttf
    - family: Charter
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Charter.ttf
```